# Mock ApplicationUserManager for Unit Testing in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I have the following controller (WebApi):

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("customers/{custId:guid}/carts")]
public class CartsController : BaseApiController
{
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public CartsController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("", Name = "GetCart")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(CartReturnModel))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCartAsync([FromUri] Guid custId)
    {
        if (User.Identity != null)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var user = await this.AppUserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    // restrict access to self and account admins
                    if (user.Customer_Id == custId || User.IsInRole("system_admin") || User.IsInRole("accounts_author") || User.IsInRole("accounts_reviewer"))
                    {
                        var tmr = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
                        tmr.Start();

                        var cust = await unitOfWork.Customers.GetCustomerByShippingAddress(custId);

                        if (cust != null)
                        {
                            var cart = await unitOfWork.CartItems.GetCustomerCart(cust);

                            tmr.Stop();
                            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetCartAsync took " + tmr.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");

                            return Ok(this.TheModelFactory.Create(cust, cart.ToList()));
                        }

                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    return Unauthorized();
                }
            }
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
}
}
```

This controller derives from a base controller:

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    public BaseApiController()
    {
    }

    private ModelFactory _modelFactory;
    protected ModelFactory TheModelFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_modelFactory == null)
            {
                _modelFactory = new ModelFactory(this.Request, this.AppUserManager);
            }
            return _modelFactory;
        }
    }

    private ApplicationUserManager _AppUserManager = null;
    protected ApplicationUserManager AppUserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _AppUserManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
    }

    private ApplicationRoleManager _AppRoleManager = null;
    protected ApplicationRoleManager AppRoleManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _AppRoleManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationRoleManager>();
        }
    }



    protected IHttpActionResult GetErrorResult(IdentityResult result)
    {
        if (result == null)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            if (result.Errors != null)
            {
                foreach (string error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
                }
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // No ModelState errors are available to send, so just return an empty BadRequest.
                return BadRequest();
            }

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

For the past week, I have been trying to unit test the controller method GetCartAsync. But it is always returning Assert.IsNotNull failed and I can't understand why. Here is the test:

```
 [TestMethod]
public async Task GetCart() {
    {
        IList<CartItem> cart = new List<CartItem>()
        {
            new CartItem
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("f1f1f790-1d13-4416-b079-5f41bcedc4ab")
                },
                new CartItem
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("1294782a-4dd7-4445-a451-590069eaa3aa")
                },
                new CartItem
                {
                    Id = Guid.Parse("e04027e6-70af-45cc-9e16-deec23671c1a")
                }
        };

    var account = new UserAccount { UserName = "m", Email = "m@m.com" };
    var mockAppManager = new Mock<ApplicationUserManager>();
    mockAppManager.Setup(c => c.FindByNameAsync("m")).ReturnsAsync(account);


    var mockRepository = new Mock<jCtrl.Services.IUnitOfWork>();
    mockRepository.Setup(x => x.CartItems.GetCustomerCart(It.IsAny<Customer>(), It.IsAny<bool>())).ReturnsAsync(cart.AsEnumerable());

    var controller = new CartsController(mockRepository.Object){
        Request = new HttpRequestMessage {RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost/customers/9efa5332-85dc-4a49-b7af-8807742244f1/carts")},
        Configuration = new HttpConfiguration(),
        User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("fake_username"))
    };


    controller.Request.SetOwinContext(new OwinContext());

    // Act
    var custId = Guid.Parse("9efa5332-85dc-4a49-b7af-8807742244f1");

    // Act
    var actionResult = await controller.GetCartAsync(custId);
    var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<CartReturnModel>;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult);
    Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult.Content);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, contentResult.Content.ItemCount);
}
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong here. It's causing me a massive headache.

Comment: Any idea anyone out there

Answer (score 1):

Your `ApiController.User` property is not set up for the test.

I'm more surprised that `User.Identity != null` didn't give you a NRE. Granted. If that got passed. then it would be returning a `NotFoundResult` according to your method under test.

This would cause the cast

```
var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<CartReturnModel>;
```

to be `null`, causing your assertion to fail.

You need to set up a fake `User` for the test.

```
var controller = new CartsController(mockRepository.Object){
    Request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost/customers/9efa5332-85dc-4a49-b7af-8807742244f1/carts"),  },
    Configuration = new HttpConfiguration(),
    User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("fake_username"))
};
```

You should also make the test async as well.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetCart() {
    //Arrange
    //...other code omitted for brevity
    var username = "m";
    var customerGuid = "9efa5332-85dc-4a49-b7af-8807742244f1"; 
    var account = new UserAccount { UserName = username, Email = "m@m.com" };
    var mockAppManager = new Mock<ApplicationUserManager>();
    mockAppManager.Setup(c => c.FindByNameAsync(username)).ReturnsAsync(account);


    var mockRepository = new Mock<jCtrl.Services.IUnitOfWork>();
    mockRepository.Setup(x => x.CartItems.GetCustomerCart(It.IsAny<Customer>(), It.IsAny<bool>())).ReturnsAsync(cart.AsEnumerable());

    var requestUri = new Uri(string.Format("http://localhost/customers/{0}/carts", customerGuid));
    var controller = new CartsController(mockRepository.Object){
        Request = new HttpRequestMessage {RequestUri = requestUri},
        Configuration = new HttpConfiguration(),
        User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username))
    };


    var custId = Guid.Parse(customerGuid);

   // Act
    var actionResult = await controller.GetCartAsync(custId);
    var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<CartReturnModel>;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult);
    Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult.Content);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, contentResult.Content.ItemCount);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but the above test is still failing. I now have:

Comment: This is still failing the test with System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: context

Comment: Still nothing...any ideas ?

Comment: This is really frustrating me now - I cannot figure out why the user is still null

Comment: which user. the IPrinciple or the IdentityUser you try to get from manager?

Comment: I get IdentityUser

Comment: I'm using Owin as well don't know if that makes a difference?

Comment: ok now I'm getting confused by your comments. i figured out the owin part. what is still null. you have multiple variables that could be considered the user so it is not clear which one you are referring to.

Comment: var user = await this.AppUserManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name); This line keeps returning null

Comment: Why does this keep on happening even though I have done as you said?

Comment: You have to setup the mocked AppUserManager to return what you want for your test

Comment: Right ok I get you, how do I do it?

Comment: Update the question with your changes so I know what you have so far.

Comment: Is that right? see updated code. Still not passing the test

Comment: Update `your question` not this answer. But i have an idea of what you are trying.

Comment: rename the question to what?

Comment: No dont rename question. put code changes in your original question.

Comment: Here is the thing. You have a lot of issues with how your code is written. which will make this answer very long. as soon as i point out one problem you will run right into the next issue which will cause the back and forth to go on for a long time.

Comment: There are too many concerns in your code. each with its own issue. this method needs to be redesigned and simplified.

Comment: Any suggestions Nkosi?

Comment: thinking. trying to see how to best advise you

Comment: Right. you need to change your approach to how you access the user managers via owin to make your class more testable. That's as high level as i've gotten so far.

Comment: Will you give me more detail though or is that it?

Comment: I do have this in my Startup class:            app.CreatePerOwinContext(jCtrlContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);

Comment: Like i said before it will involve a lot of changes that are too much to get into here.

Comment: in unit testing you want to mock the dependencies of your subject under test. in this case you only show one dependency `IUnitOfWork` in teh controller constructor. which is misleading as it also depends on other classes vis IOwinContext under the hood in the base controller. kind of like an iceberg. you are going to have to re look at the controller and when it needs to perform its job and then design the class properly. that top is now way outside of the scope of your original question.

Comment: how is IUnitOfWork being resolved? via owin or some other DI framework?

Comment: It is injected via Unity

Comment: then abstract the classes you are getting with owin and inject those via unity as well.

Comment: Im only injecting unitofwork and nothing else - is that right

Comment: You can inject other services as well.

Comment: which ones do you mean though.. all of my repositories?

Comment: no. ApplicationUserManager and the others that you have in your base controller.

Comment: but applicationusermanager is not abstract its just a class like public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<UserAccount>{}

Comment: exactly, and that is the point i am trying to get you to understand. you create an interface and wrap the managers in an implementation and inject them into your controller. that way for your tests you can easily mock the interfaces

Comment: Thats great thanks for your help. But Nkosi I want to ask you something what is ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationRoleManager used for and how does this relate to OWIN. Can you explain at a very basic level

Comment: At a high level it is part of identity management. a framework for the authentication and authorization of user accounts.